# Evitar duplicar url aspx c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Quisiera consultar si es posible hacer lo siguiente:

Evitar duplicar la misma pagina en la pestaña del navegador. 
Les explico, tengo un link que es www.registrar.aspx, quiero que cuando copien el link y peguen en otra pestaña no se cargue y no exista duplicidad de páginas.

Disculpen de antemano que no ponga el código

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entendí  usted podria tener un problema con la vulnerabilidad Cross-site Reference Forgery (CSRF) que se trata de que desde otra página (pestaña) el usuario pueda ser suplantado para enviar información al servidor mediante un post request.

Si ese fuera el caso  es de Anti-Forgery Tokens. ASP.NET cuenta con Anti-Forgery Tokens para evitar la falsificación de solicitudes entre sitios. Implementando no importa si duplican la pestaña porque no permitirá el envió de datos igualmente es capaz de detener un ataque desde otro sitio. Hay abundante información en Youtube y Google.

Ahora si el asunto es un más sencillo sugiero que lo maneje con JavaScript. Deshabilitando el clic derecho y el copiar y pegar en esa página. También hay números ejemplos en internet sobre cómo hacer eso.

Comment: Creo que se llama "Cross-Site Request Forgery"